# How to call storedproc using openJPA and map to existing entity

Tags: stored-procedures, openjpa

I am trying to figure out how to call a stored procedure using openJPA

How do I do that?  I assume it is the same as calling a namedQuery, but I can't find anywhere online where to do this.
I can't find one tutorial.

Also, how do you map it to an existing entity?  Just have a `("nameOfStoredProc", NameOfEntity.class)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the OpenJPA user manual.... [Creating SQL Queries](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/docbook/manual.html#jpa_overview_sqlquery_create)

> In addition to SELECT statements, OpenJPA supports stored procedure
>   invocations as SQL queries. OpenJPA will assume any SQL that does not
>   begin with the SELECT keyword (ignoring case) is a stored procedure
>   call, and invoke it as such at the JDBC level.

```
EntityManager em = ...;
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("StoredProcName", Magazine.class);
processMagazines(query.getResultList());
```

Comment: Any idea how to do this with the oracle stored procedure taking multiple params one of which is a ref cursor?

Comment: is it even possible?  I have been searching the net and it doesn't look like it.